# Javascript scroll text function - array.shift() is not a function

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm trying to make scroll text function, but i get an error in Chrome console : "nasArray[i].shift is not a function". What's wrong ?

```
var text = 'Milica';
var text1 = 'Danka';
var text2 = 'Marko';

var stext = text.split('');
var stext1 = text1.split('');
var stext2 = text2.split('');
var nasArray = [text, text1, text2];

var i = 0;

var scroll = document.getElementById('scroll');

function start() {
    if (nasArray[i].length > 0) {
        scroll.innerHTML += nasArray[i].shift();
        setTimeout(start, 200);
    } else {
        i++;
        if (i > 2) {
            i = 0;
        }
        scroll.innerHTML = '';
        start();
    }
}

start();
```

Comment: It simply means `nasArray[i]` is not array.

Comment: ^ `nasArray` is an Array of Strings

Comment: isnt it `nasArray.shift()` ?

Comment: You probably wan to define `nasArray` as `var nasArray = [stext, stext1, stext2]`

Answer (score 1):

`shift()` is a [method of Arrays](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/shift), not strings. Because you are indexing the strings in the `nasArray[i]` reference there is a type mismatch.

Try
`scroll.innerHTML += nasArray.shift()` instead

Answer (score 1):

nasArray[i] is not an array. Those elements are strings. Use the shift function of the array instead.

edit: You can also do what Luca suggested in the comments. `var nasArray = [stext, stext1, stext2]`. This will work because `stext`, `stext1`, etc. were created by the split function, and are thus arrays.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to call `.shift()` on strings, not arrays.

If you want to delete the first letter of each word, you should build your array with the splitted words :

```
var nasArray = [stext, stext1, stext2];
```

If you want to remove the first word from `nasArray`, simply call `.shift()` on `nasArray` and not `nasArray[i]`.

Comment: This is the same as jakemingolla and psdanielxu's answers that were posted while I was writing this one.